# Instaling SpaCy for Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spacy

Hi guys I'm having a problem with installing SpaCy on Windows/Anaconda.
I was trying:

**conda install -c conda-forge spacy**

And I'm getting an error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
**Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions**
```

Does it mean that my anaconda version is not compatible with the SpaCy?
Do you guys know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: it means that at least one package in your environment is incompatible with spacy - which one is hard to tell. Sometimes the output of conflicting packages gives you a clue.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? Which channel(s) are you using? Is that the entire error output?